# Tomcat shows 404

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I've got a Java EE project that works ok in Eclipse. But when I deploy it to a server with a normal Tomcat-7 it shows a 404 error on every servlet page (while .jsp works).

I've tried to deploy there a .war file and tried to just copy the whole project folder including the WEB-INF directory. The result is the same.

web.xml file contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         version="2.5">
  <display-name>acs</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>jsp</display-name>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.svg</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.kml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The every servlet class contains annotations like that

```
@WebServlet("/full")
```

So why it's happening? And is there a way to know where Tomcat trying to search that servlets? Or something. So now I'm like standing before the wall and it shows me 404 and I'm do not have a tiny idea what's going wrong...

Comment: If you develop on Windows: there file names are case-insensitive. And for Unix (and jars) file paths are case sensitive. Another secundary issue: probably the server has UTF-8 encoding, and you Windows-1252 or the like. Check that the encoding of the JSP sources are correct if you use special characters. -- Of course you might have changed the servlet context: http localhost 8080 / servlet / x.jpg versus http my.com / x.jpg.

Comment: No, both development machine and server runs on GNU/Linux both using UTF-8 charset.

Comment: Further guessing: maybe one server unpacks the war, the other not. May owner/rights issue. Good luck anyway.

Comment: Well.. actually I develop without .war and deploy to server also just folder. But when I've tried deploy .war Tomact unpacked it and created proper folder with classes etc. But did not find its...

Comment: Well I've investigated **where the trouble was located**. It was in the `<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>`. If I delete that string the trouble _mystically_ disappeared. But why??? It looks like Tomcat-7 looks for index.html in folder requested in URL instead of looking for proper servlet. And finds a proper rule `*.html` for default servlet and it searches for such file (index.html) and obviously not find it...

Answer (score 0):

For every servlet we are adding 2 main tags < servlet > and < servlet-mapping > like

```
   <servlet>
    <display-name>jsp</display-name>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

While for "**default**" servlet I have not found the < servlet > tag with **servlet-class** mapping

Comment: Well i've inserted there servlet tag for default with class `org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet` as it described [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html). But nothing changes.